# How do I use the If grouping function to eliminate null values in a row

Tags: sql, mysql

> Write a SELECT statement that answers this question:
>
> What is the total quantity purchased for each product within each
> category?
>
> Return these columns:
>
> - The category_name column from the category table
> - The product_name column from the products table
> - The total quantity purchased for each product with orders in the Order_Items table
>
> Use the `WITH ROLLUP` operator to include rows that give a summary for
> each category name as well as a row that gives the grand total.
>
> Use the `IF` and `GROUPING` functions to replace null values in the
> `category_name` and `product_name` columns with literal values if
> they’re for summary rows.

```
select 
    categories.category_name
  , products.product_name
  , sum(order_items.quantity) as total_qty_purchased

from categories
inner join products on products.category_id = categories.category_id
inner join order_items on order_items.product_id = products.product_id
group by categories. category_name, product_name with rollup;
```

This returned null values. I'm expected to eliminate the null value rows using the if grouping function, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: `if they're for summary rows` tells you the need for `IF`, and `ROLLUP` will set those columns to `NULL` for a summary row. You pretty much just need to modify your `SELECT` to display the output as desired.

Comment: What have you tried, using the `IF` and `GROUPING` functions? Docs here https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-grouping-function/

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: `I'm expected to eliminate the null value rows` then why do with rollup at all?  or do you mean to keep the category total rows but remove the grand total?   show your expected output.

Comment: @ysth per the question, "replace null values ... with literal values".

Comment: @ysth The instructions say to produce a grand total.

Comment: `coalesce(categories.category_name, 'this is sub total')`. You'll also need a case where both columns are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IF` for the category name, since this is a two-way condition. It's only null for the grand total.

Use `CASE` for the product name because there are three possibilities: it will be null for the grand total or category subtotal, non-null for the product total. For the grand total you don't need to put anything in the product name column of the result, because the category has already been replaced with `Grand Total`.

```
select 
    IF(c.category_name IS NULL, 'Grand Total', c.category_name) AS category_name
  , CASE 
        WHEN c.category_name IS NULL AND p.product_name IS NULL THEN ''
        WHEN p.product_name IS NULL THEN 'Subtotal'
        ELSE p.product_name
    END AS product_name
  , sum(oi.quantity) as total_qty_purchased

from categories AS c
inner join products AS p on p.category_id = c.category_id
inner join order_items AS oi on oi.product_id = p.product_id
group by c.category_name, p.product_name with rollup;
```